# Understanding Wikipedia's example of Haskell's Maybe monad

Tags: haskell, monads, option-type

I think I understand the monad concept in Haskell, i.e., the role of >>= and return. However, I'm a little confused by the the syntax of the application of them in this [Wikipedia example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming)#The_Maybe_monad).

```
add :: Maybe Int -> Maybe Int -> Maybe Int
add mx my =             -- Adds two values of type (Maybe Int), where each input value can be Nothing
  mx >>= (\x ->         -- Extracts value x if mx is not Nothing
    my >>= (\y ->       -- Extracts value y if my is not Nothing
      return (x + y)))  -- Wraps value (x+y), returning the sum as a value of type (Maybe Int)
```

I understand clearly the intent of this function. I'm just a little confused about the order of evaluation. May anyone show line by line which part of the function is evaluated (supposing that mx and my are of type Maybe Int and mx = Just x' and my = Just y', where x' and y' are Int values)?

I think it is something like that:

```
mx >>= (\x -> my >>= (\y -> return (x + y)))    --- original
(\x -> my >>= (\y -> return (x + y))) x         --- mx is Just Int, then apply the function in x
(\x -> my >>= (\y -> return (x + y)))           --- x is the first argument. Then I get confused. What's the second part of the function?
```

Comment: Your last line is incorrect. That's not how beta reduction works. Drop `x->` after the first `(`.

Comment: just do the same again for `my` .... (if it's `Just y` you get `(\y -> return (x+y)) y = return (x+y) = Just (x+y)`)

Comment: of course if any one of them is `Nothing` you end up with nothing (because `Nothing >>= f = Nothing` by definition)

Comment: That's right. By understanding beta reduction the evaluation became clearer. I added my own answer. Thanks for both of you.

Answer (score 3):

n.m. gave the key for the answer, as I was replacing incorrectly the values.

We have to apply beta reduction.

Quoting the Haskell Wiki:

> For example, suppose we apply the function
>
> (\x -> 2*x*x + y) to the value 7. To calculate the result, we
>   substitute 7 for every free occurrence of x, and so the application of
>   the function (\x -> 2*x*x + y)(7) is reduced to the result
>
> 2*7*7 + y

(http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Beta_reduction)

Then, applying that to the function I presented,

```
mx >>= (\x -> my >>= (\y -> return (x + y)))

(\x -> my >>= (\y -> return (x + y))) x'

my >>= (\y -> return (x' + y)))

(\y -> return (x' + y)) y'

return (x' + y')
```

Comment: Added a line to your steps to be more consistent (i.e. showing the second application of the `(>>=)` operator.